# how to use the operator OR in regex for potgresql database

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have an unconventional JSON column in my table: 
This is the possible values :

```
[{"tarif pour 1 :":"$40,00"},{"Réduction :":"-$10,00 "}]

[{"Full Fare For 10 :":"$50.00"},{"Promotion:":"-$20.00"}]
```

my goal is using `postgresql` function `substring` how to get the values

```
$40,00
$50.00
```

I could do it but using 2 separate REGEX like:

```
    SELECT
         , substring(column, '"Full [Ff]are [Ff]or.+?:":"(.+?)"') AS value_1
         , substring(column, '"[Pp]lein [Tt]arif [Pp]our.+?:":"(.+?)"') AS value_2
FROM table
```

How can I include the both REGEX in my column to show the dollar amount after either or the strings that starts with `[Pp]lein [Tt]arif [Pp]our.+?:":"` OR `[Ff]ull [Ff]are [Ff]or.+?:":"`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

```
with a_table(a_column) as (
values
    ('[{"Plein tarif pour 1 :":"$40,00"},{"Réduction :":"-$10,00 "}]'),
    ('[{"Full Fare For 10 :":"$50.00"},{"Promotion:":"-$20.00"}]')
)
select 
    coalesce(
        substring(a_column, '"Full [Ff]are [Ff]or.+?:":"(.+?)"'),
        substring(a_column, '"[Pp]lein [Tt]arif [Pp]our.+?:":"(.+?)"')
    ) as value
from a_table;

 value  
--------
 $40,00
 $50.00
(2 rows)
```